# how make input text field like an option of radio button wit simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button, simple-form

How can I render an input field for an of option radio buttons group with simple_form gem Rails?

I am trying render to option "other" input field see below:
`<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :options,
               [["first_option", "Option 1"],
               ["second_option", "Option 2"],
               ["other", "<input type='text' name='other_reason' />" ]],
               :first, :last %>`

Basically I am trying reproduce http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pgyA2/ but with simple_form.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
  $("reason_input").keyup(function(){
                $("hidden_radio").val($(this).val())
              })



          <%= f.radio_button_tag 'reason', "Fit Description" %>
          <%= f.radio_button_tag 'reason', "Suspicious Behavior" %>
          <%= f.radio_button_tag 'reason', "No Reason Given" %>
          <%= f.radio_button_tag 'reason', "Other" %>
          <%= f.radio_button_tag 'reason', nil, :id => :hidden_radio, :style => "display:none" %>
          <%= text_field :reason_input, :id => :reason_input %>
```

Comment: where do you get reason_input from? does that need to be another attribute in the DB?